# RealTime Graph Entry

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth

Please understand that I am using Google Translator because I do not understand English well.

I am currently working on an application that draws an EMG sensor value sent by Arduino via Bluetooth communication and a smartphone draws a graph based on that value.

Currently the application configuration has one activity and one fragment.

The Bluetooth function is in the activity and the graph is in the fragment.

I want to have the graph drawn only when the value comes in via Bluetooth communication. What should I do?

The code now depends on the fact that the fragment receives a value, even though the fragment is requesting a value.

Fragment

```
   private void feedMultiple() {
    if (thread != null)
        thread.interrupt();

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            addEntry();
        }
    };

    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (loop) {
                // Don't generate garbage runnables inside the loop
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }


            }

        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

Activity

```
void beginListenForData() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    readBufferPosition = 0;                 
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];            

    mWorkerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    int byteAvailable = mInputStream.available();   
                    if(byteAvailable > 0) {                        
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[byteAvailable];                           
                        mInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0; i<byteAvailable; i++) {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];


                            if(b == mCharDelimiter) {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];                                                                      
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);

                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes,"UTF-8");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable(){                                       
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        //raw = data.split("#");
                                        bundle.putString("yValue1", data); 

                                    }

                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {    
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "데이터 수신 중 오류가 발생 했습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();            
                }
            }
        }

    });
    mWorkerThread.start();
}
```

Comment: "I want to have the graph drawn only when the value comes in via Bluetooth communication. What should I do?" Is this the problem? What is not working or what do you want ? Please clarify in detail

Comment: I want to be able to see the EMG sensor value displayed on the Arduino serial monitor accurately in the graph application of the smartphone.